# How to prevent illegal submit request?

Tags: php, forms, validation, isset

I am new to PHP so as I am learning I just discovered that you can go directly to a page like domain.com/process.php and the page would still run.

How can I prevent a user from directly accessing the page and make sure they got to the process.php after they have submitted the form?

Comment: Maybe you should read more about CSRF protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, use this code :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo 'Try accessing this page by pressing submit button'. '<br />';
echo "<a href='form.html'>Goto Form Page</a>";
exit();
}
?>

// here 'submit' is the name attribute within your input tag for submit button
/*
It simply means if submit button is not pressed, echo the following message and 
exit don't run anything else. You can also use die('Your message here') 
instead of exit();
*/
```

Comment: Check this out. I've done some edits to make it more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this? Perhaps there is another or better way of doing this, but I'm not sure.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     ///process form
 }
```

in most cases this should work, though some cases it may not, in this case you could add a hidden field:

```
<input type='hidden' name='submit' />
```

The hidden field should always be submitted.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but the page still runs through.  Does the processing code need to be in brackets? Can't i just use it to see if submit was clicked or not?

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I am not sure what's going on.  I am using the same snippets you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Use session to prevent users from directly accessing `process.php`. Like in `index.php` use `session_start(); $_SESSION['access']="true";` and in `process.php` page,

```
session_start(); 
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['access'])){
?>
<form >.....your process form here....
<?php
}else{
echo "Direct access deny";
die;
}
```

Even this can be automated, first go to index page then process page automatically, you can use captcha to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 examples of how to stop process.php from running both using a combination of a set session and a check on if the request is a POST (others have mentioned just checking `submit` is set but a bot would only need add that value to its params, but by using a random key the bot would have to visit the form page and get the key at least once, also for some extra security you could unset the session variable so process.php will only run once per form view, this would slow down (but not stop) a brute force or spammer):

**Form Page**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['process_key']=md5(microtime(true));
?>
<p>Form</p>
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?=$_SESSION['process_key'];?>">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST' && isset($_SESSION['process_key']) && $_POST['key'] == $_SESSION['process_key']){
    //process form
   ...
   ...
 unset($_SESSION['process_key']);
}else{
    header('Location: ./index.php');
    die;
}
?>
```

Or an alternative method would be to post the form back to the script and include process.php.

```
<?php 
//Form Page
session_start();
define('RUN',true);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST' && isset($_SESSION['process_key']) && $_POST['key'] == $_SESSION['process_key']){
    //process form
    include('process.php');
    die;
}else{
$_SESSION['process_key']=md5(microtime(true));  
//echo form
?>
<p>Form</p>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?=$_SESSION['process_key'];?>">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
<?php
} ?>
```

Then have at the top of process.php so it cant be run if its not included from another file:

`<?php if (!defined("RUN")){header ("Location: ./index.php");} ?>`